# Raspberry-Pi 3: LAMP Web Server with WordPress

Tags: mysql, wordpress, mariadb, raspberry-pi3, lamp

I want to build a LAMP Web Server with WordPress using a Raspberry-Pi 3 and I have followed this tutorial:

https://projects.raspberrypi.org/en/projects/lamp-web-server-with-wordpress

I am having some problems with MySQL installation, because using the command

```
$ sudo apt-get install mysql-server php-mysql -y
```

I can't select the root password, as written in the tutorial. Then, I am not able to enter the MySQL database with command

```
$ mysql -uroot -ppassword
```

neither using

```
$ mysql -uroot -p
```

The only way to enter the database is to use (without any password)

```
$ sudo mysql -uroot
```

In the last step of tutorial, when I have to select the database connection details, I don't know which password to use.

Can anyone help me?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There are two "roots".

The password for the OS's root is used for `sudo`.

The password for MySQL's root is used for `mysql -u root -p`.

There should be no need for `sudo mysql ...`.  But when you do it, first the OS has control and either remembers that you are sudo, or prompts something like

```
[sudo] password for root:
```

Then `mysql` gets control and sees the `-p`, so prompts you:

```
Enter password:
```

During the setup, were you ever asked to create a mysql root password?  If not, then `mysql -uroot` would get into mysql without a password.  You *should* create a password then for security.

Answer (score 0):

This is possibly caused by the change that Debian did to MariaDB. They enabled the [UNIX socket authentication plugin](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/authentication-plugin-unix-socket/) by default for newer versions. This would explain why no password is required.

If you want to enable password authentication, you could create a separate `root` user account. This appears to be required to complete the tutorial.

```
CREATE USER 'root'@'127.0.0.1' IDENTIFIED BY 'my-password';
```

This creates the user `root` with the password `my-password` which you can then add to the WordPress configuration.